# CMOS op amp subtractor deviation

Tags: cmos, mixer

I constructed a single stage differential amp and used it to make a subtractor. The input amplitudes are 2 mV and 3 mV, however the output is about 1.4 mV. Can anyone tell me why?

[image: circuit]
[image: wave]

Comment: Your open loop gain is crappy so how can expect a true and accurate subtraction with just negative feedback from M4?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply, I just begin to take some analog circuit courses recently so I can not understand what you said, why you say my gain is crappy? Are you saying my differential amp is not correct?

Comment: BTW, the gain is about 36dB for single input.

Comment: Most op-amps have dc gains around 1 million to achieve dc accuracy - your gain is 63.1 plus, input offset errors will account for any other errors.